# Invalid token || C# Telegram-bot

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Я решил попробовать написать Телеграм бота. Посмотрел несколько видео уроков. И всё пытался повторить. Только столкнулся с проблемой

> System.ArgumentException: 'Invalid format. A valid token looks like "1234567:4TT8bAc8GHUspu3ERYn-KGcvsvGB9u_n4ddy". '

Какая может быть причина данной ошибки?

Вот код:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Telegram.Bot;
using Telegram.Bot.Args;
using Telegram.Bot.Types.ReplyMarkups;

namespace Telegram_Bot
{
    class Program
    {
          private static string Token { get; set; } = "токен";
          private static TelegramBotClient client;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            client = new TelegramBotClient(Token); //как только запустить программу останавливаеться на этом месте с ошибкой
            client.StartReceiving();
            client.OnMessage += OnMessageHandler;
            Console.ReadLine();
            client.StopReceiving();
        }

        private static async void OnMessageHandler(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
        {
            var msg = e.Message;
            if (msg.Text != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Пришло сообщение с текстом: {msg.Text}");
                switch (msg.Text)
                {
                    case "Стикер":
                        await client.SendStickerAsync(
                            chatId: msg.Chat.Id,
                            sticker: "ссылка на стикер",
                            replyToMessageId: msg.MessageId,
                            replyMarkup: GetButtons());
                        break;
                    case "Картинка":
                        await client.SendPhotoAsync(
                            chatId: msg.Chat.Id,
                            photo: "сслыка на фото",
                            replyMarkup: GetButtons());
                        break;

                    default:
                        await client.SendTextMessageAsync(msg.Chat.Id, "Выберите команду: ", replyMarkup: GetButtons());
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        private static IReplyMarkup GetButtons()
        {
            return new ReplyKeyboardMarkup
            {
                Keyboard = new List<List<KeyboardButton>>
                {
                    new List<KeyboardButton>{ new KeyboardButton { Text = "Стикер"}, new KeyboardButton { Text = "Картинка"} },
                    new List<KeyboardButton>{ new KeyboardButton { Text = "123"}, new KeyboardButton { Text = "456"} }
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А процедуру регистрации телеграмм-бота (через Bot-Father) Вы прошли? Именно там выдаётся токен, котрый Вам надо использовать в своём боте

Answer (score 1):

У меня такая же проблема. Я использую библиотеку Telegram.Bot, проблема в том, что Ваш идентификатор пользователя не входит в Int32. А в данной библиотеке видимо еще не поменяли данный момент. [image: введите сюда описание изображения] Предлагаю вам поменять взять 16 версию библиотеки.

Answer (score 1):

просто поменяй версию на 16.0.2 тогда всё будет работать(у меня проблема была такая же)

Answer (score 0):

Кстати, в версии Telegram.Bot 18.0.0 нужно писать код немного по другому...

```
    private static IReplyMarkup GetButtons()
    {
        //return new ReplyKeyboardMarkup // прошлая версия Telegram.Bot
        return new ReplyKeyboardMarkup(new KeyboardButton(null))
        {
            Keyboard = new List<List<KeyboardButton>>
            {
                //new List<KeyboardButton>{ new KeyboardButton { Text = "Стикер"}, new KeyboardButton { Text = "Картинка"} },  // прошлая версия Telegram.Bot
                new List<KeyboardButton>{ new KeyboardButton("Стикер"), new KeyboardButton("Картинка") },
                //new List<KeyboardButton>{ new KeyboardButton { Text = "123"}, new KeyboardButton { Text = "456"} }  // прошлая версия Telegram.Bot
                new List<KeyboardButton>{ new KeyboardButton("123"), new KeyboardButton("456") }
            },
            // доп. опции клавиатуры
            ResizeKeyboard = true,
            OneTimeKeyboard = false,
            Selective = false
        };
    }
```

П.С. Сам долго мучился, пришел к такому варианту, скидываю код, вдруг кому будет информация полезна!

Ну или ещё проще, без опций как у вас

```
    private static IReplyMarkup GetButtons()
    {
        ReplyKeyboardMarkup rkm = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup(new KeyboardButton(null));
        rkm.Keyboard = new KeyboardButton[][]{ new KeyboardButton[]{("Стикер"), ("Картинка") },
                                               new KeyboardButton[]{("123"), ("456") }};
        return rkm;
    }
```